# How to aggregate and replace data using .net driver in mongoDb?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a problem with mongodb lookup. Here is basic example how you can reproduce my issue

```
public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class OrderProduct
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<OrderProduct> OrderProducts { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get order and all related products.
So here is my query

```
 var filter = Builders<Entities.Order>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
        var result = await Collection.Aggregate()
            .Match(filter)
            .Lookup("Product", "OrderProducts.ProductId", "_id", "Products")
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

So basically I am successfully getting data from collection, but in a bit different format. I am getting BsonDocument

```
{
   { 
      "_id":"5ab0c1ec36e4e937302ee1df",
      "Total":225,
      "OrderProducts":
       [
          {
             "ProductId":"5ab0c1dc36e4e937302ee1de",
             "Quantity":2
          }
       ],
       Products:
       [
          {
              "_id":"5ab0c1dc36e4e937302ee1de",
              "Name":"Test product",
              "Price":20
          }
       ]
    }
```

But I would like to get document like this:

```
{
   { 
      "_id":"5ab0c1ec36e4e937302ee1df",
      "Total":225,
      "OrderProducts":
       [
          {
             "_id":"5ab0c1dc36e4e937302ee1de",
              "Name":"Test product",
              "Price":20,
             "Quantity":2
          }
       ]           
    }
```

Do you have any ideas how to implement this ?  I found operator mergeObject  but I dont have any idea how to add it here. And one more: is there more elegant way to specify lookup ?  not hardcoded strings as here  `.Lookup("Product", "OrderProducts.ProductId", "_id", "Products")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid hardcoding strings you can use `nameof` operator. To achieve desired shape you need to get rid of arrays (using `Unwind`) then use `Lookup` and then group back to single `Order`

Try:

```
    var filter = Builders<Order>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
    var result = Collection.Aggregate<Order>()
        .Match(filter)
        .Unwind(a => a.OrderProducts)
        .Lookup(nameof(Product), $"{nameof(Order.OrderProducts)}.{nameof(OrderProduct.ProductId)}", "_id", nameof(Product))
        .Unwind(nameof(Product))
        .Group(new BsonDocument
          {
               { "_id", "_id" },
               { nameof(Order.Total) , new BsonDocument("$first", $"${nameof(Order.Total)}")},
               { nameof(Order.OrderProducts),
                    new BsonDocument("$push",
                        new BsonDocument() {
                            { "_id", $"${nameof(Product)}._id" },
                            { nameof(Product.Name), $"${nameof(Product)}.{nameof(Product.Name)}" },
                            { nameof(Product.Price), $"${nameof(Product)}.{nameof(Product.Price)}" },
                            { nameof(OrderProduct.Quantity), $"${nameof(OrderProduct)}s.{nameof(OrderProduct.Quantity)}" }
                        }
               )},
          })
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks @mickl ! This approach with nameof is excelent. The same I can say about query. One more quick question: is it possible to do multiply lookups ?  For example if I will have not only 'OrderProducts' in Order , but also some other array like 'DiscountCouponsIds'.

Comment: @Oleh sure, you can chain them just as other pipeline stages, example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171807/mongodb-group-data-from-multiple-collection-having-same-document-structure/49178787#49178787

Comment: Thanks @mickl ! I got some strange result. I added to existing query one more Lookup and Unwind
.Lookup(nameof(Entities.DiscountCoupon), $"{nameof(Entities.Order.Coupons)}.{nameof(Entities.Common.DiscountCoupon.CouponId)}", "_id", nameof(Entities.DiscountCoupon))
.Unwind(nameof(Entities.DiscountCoupon))

but for some reason I am getting 2 Coupons (duplicates) , but there is only one. I guess its because Unwind, right ? Or I missed something ?

Comment: @Oleh yes, in fact unwind duplicates the data so you need to use Group to inverse the duplication

Comment: So for each Lookup Unwind I need separate Group than , right @mickl ?

Comment: @Oleh not always, lookup is like left outer join in SQL but SQL duplicates rows from left set whereas Lookup embeds an array. If you have one to one relationship you can use unwind to get single element instead of array. For one to many you'll get duplicates. Please create another question if you need further help. I'll try to look at it